# $1\over n$ is not element of $\ell^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

My teacher said  $1\over n$ is not element of $\ell^1$ .I know if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty|{1\over n}| < \infty$ , it is element of $\ell^1$.
Let's consider the series $(x_i)=(1,{1\over 2}, {1\over 3} , . . .)$ .It seems to me  if i sum  all the component of the series up , it will be smaller than $2$  so it is finite. 
     Is it right ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}  = \frac{25}{12} > 2$.

Comment: Look up "harmonic series".

Comment: I  got it . Thank you.